# 12 V to 5 V with highest current possible

Tags: switching-regulator, step-down

I have a 12 V, 14 A DC power source and I would like to step it down to 5 V DC with the least amount of loss of current.  Theoretically, by stepping down to 5 V is should be able to get as much as 33 A.

Is there a switching regulator out there that will do this or what components would be necessary to do this?

Comment: "least amount of loss",  so your budget is unlimited?

Answer (score 1):

> *Is there a switching regulator out there that will do this*

It's called a buck regulator and some can be as high as 95% power efficient. That means, with 12 volts and 14 amps on the input (a power of 168 watts), the output power could be up to 160 watts or 5 volts and 32 amps.

Bearing in mind that shopping questions are off-topic on this site, so there's no point trying to recommend one but, if you find one that looks good for the job, I'd be happy to see if it might fit the bill. You'll need to look for a synchronous buck regulator i.e. one that has an active flyback MOSFET instead of a regular diode.

Comment: at 160W a forwards converter might be a better fit.

Comment: *"It's called a buck regulator"* A company I used to work for made LLC Resonant Converters, 97-99% efficiency.

Comment: @Jasen power efficiency would be a tad less than 90% I suspect.

Comment: @Huisman sounds like a good reason to make an answer.

Comment: @Andyaka would you be able to suggest a part number of a buck regulator that would work?

Comment: Not off the top of my head but try looking for old Linear Technology parts (now owned by ADI). Texas Instruments is also a place to look. Maybe the LTC3709.

Comment: Nah, I remember not enough about these converters to write a *decent* answer. Moreover, seeing how broad the question is, I wonder if it worth recalling the details (which is needed to obtain the 98%).

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking this kind of question, you might find it a bit challenging to successfully build a power supply with that kind of output current/power from raw components. If you are primarily aiming to learn, don't care about time and cost, and are willing to go through multiple spins of a PCB (maybe with extra-thick copper so $$) then this may not apply.

You might want to look at commercial DC-DC modules which generally come with a guarantee of efficiency and other performance parameters. If you go to a distributor such as digikey.com and do a parametric search you can find such modules. I see one that costs $23 USD (one-off) and will provide 5V at 40A with minimum efficiency 92%, typical 94%. So at 92% you would be able to get 31A @ 5V.

You should go through this search yourself and look at (and understand) the datasheet to evaluate the commercial options.